# Trying to understand application.ontime

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a piece of code that up to this point works in, say, a "single task demand".
It's a **simple alarm**.

The user has to type a number in any cell in column A. That represents the number of seconds it will take until the alarm triggers.

Time only starts to run when the user double clicks a cell with a number, in column A. Let's call it "**calling cell**".

Upon being double clicked, "**calling cell**" becomes red (indicating the time started to run), and after that amount of time (in seconds) a routine called "**Infinite_Msgbox**" is triggered and starts to run   every 5 seconds.

"**Infinite_Msgbox**" turns "**calling cell**" into green, and simply shows (in a  message box) the time it was supposed to be triggered. And keeps repeating this message until the user double clicks "**calling cell**" again, which at this time becomes white and the alarm is stoped.

If the user double clicks "**calling cell**" before "**Infinite_Msgbox**" is triggered then the alarm is canceled and "**calling cell**" is turned to white again.

It all works just fine, **IF** only one cell is double clicked in column A.
If I try to setup a second alarm, while there's one already running, then the process gets all weird and "**Infinite_Msgbox**" shows only the time it was supposed to show for the second double click.
It keeps showing two message boxes, but not in the right time frames.

I'm using an array to keep track of each double click, but  Application.OnTime doesn't seem to care about it...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        iAlarm = Target.Row
        If iAlarm > iHighest_Alarm Then
            iHighest_Alarm = iAlarm
        End If
    
        If (Target.Interior.Color = vbWhite) Then
            Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Call Alarm_Setup(Target.Value, Target.Row)
        ElseIf (Target.Interior.Color = vbRed) Then
            Target.Interior.Color = vbWhite
            Call Alarm_Cancel(Target.Row)
        Else
            Target.Interior.Color = vbWhite
            Call Alarm_Stop(Target.Row)
        End If
    End If
 
    Cancel = True

End Sub
```

And this goes in a module:

```
Public iAlarm As Integer
Public iHighest_Alarm As Integer
Public dTime_to_Alarm() As Double
Public dTime_to_Stop_Alarm() As Double

Public Sub Alarm_Setup(ByVal sTime_to_Alarm As String, ByVal iRow As Integer)

    ReDim Preserve dTime_to_Alarm(1 To iHighest_Alarm)
    dTime_to_Alarm(iAlarm) = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Val(sTime_to_Alarm))
    Application.OnTime dTime_to_Alarm(iAlarm), "'Infinite_MsgBox """ & iRow & "'"

End Sub

Public Sub Infinite_MsgBox(ByVal iRow As Integer)

    Cells(iRow, 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    MsgBox "Alarm " & iAlarm & ": " & CDate(dTime_to_Alarm(iAlarm))

    ReDim Preserve dTime_to_Stop_Alarm(1 To iHighest_Alarm)
    dTime_to_Stop_Alarm(iAlarm) = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

    Application.OnTime dTime_to_Stop_Alarm(iAlarm), "'Infinite_MsgBox """ & iRow & "'"

End Sub

Public Sub Alarm_Cancel(ByVal iRow As Integer)

    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTime_to_Alarm(iAlarm), Procedure:="'Infinite_MsgBox """ & iRow & "'", Schedule:=False

End Sub

Public Sub Alarm_Stop(ByVal iRow As Integer)

    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTime_to_Stop_Alarm(iAlarm), Procedure:="'Infinite_MsgBox """ & iRow & "'", Schedule:=False

End Sub
```

So, how can I get Application.OnTime to work as intended?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Sheet code

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  
    Dim rw As Long
    
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
    
        If Not IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then Exit Sub
        rw = Target.Row
        
        Select Case Target.Interior.Color
            Case vbWhite
                Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
                Alarm_Setup Target.Value, rw
            Case Else
                Target.Interior.Color = vbWhite
                Alarm_Cancel rw
        End Select
        
        Cancel = True 'only cancel in Col A ?
    End If
End Sub
```

Module code - using a Scripting Dictionary to track next execution times, according to the cell row(s).

```vb
Public Alarms As Object

Public Sub Alarm_Setup(ByVal sec As String, ByVal rw As Long)
    Dim dt
    'create the dictionary if not already created
    If Alarms Is Nothing Then Set Alarms = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dt = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Val(sec))
    Application.OnTime dt, "'Infinite_MsgBox " & rw & "'"
    Alarms(rw) = dt 'add row and next time to the dictionary
End Sub

Public Sub Infinite_MsgBox(ByVal rw As Long)
    Dim dt, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("My Alarms") 'or whatever
    ws.Cells(rw, 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    
    Debug.Print "Alarm", rw, Alarms(rw)
    
    dt = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
    Application.OnTime dt, "'Infinite_MsgBox " & rw & "'"
    Alarms(rw) = dt 'update next run time
End Sub

Public Sub Alarm_Cancel(ByVal rw As Long)
    'check if there's anything scheduled for this row
    If Alarms.exists(rw) Then
        Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Alarms(rw), _
                       Procedure:="'Infinite_MsgBox " & rw & "'", _
                       Schedule:=False
        Alarms.Remove rw 'remove from Alarms
    End If
End Sub
```